# ggplot2 facet_grid repeats barplot names

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to use `facet_grid` to create a grid of bargraphs. My data looks like this:

```
> data
                          get       mean   catvar    calcvar
 1:          Mexican American  6.7423680 RIDRETH1 CIGARETTES
 2:            other Hispanic  9.3955082 RIDRETH1 CIGARETTES
 3:        non-Hispanic White 15.9486910 RIDRETH1 CIGARETTES
 4:        non-Hispanic Black 10.2582135 RIDRETH1 CIGARETTES
 5:        other non-Hispanic 11.7396250 RIDRETH1 CIGARETTES
 6:          Mexican American  0.5812325 RIDRETH1        WHR
 7:            other Hispanic  0.5688999 RIDRETH1        WHR
 8:        non-Hispanic White  0.5587113 RIDRETH1        WHR
 9:        non-Hispanic Black  0.5614028 RIDRETH1        WHR
10:        other non-Hispanic  0.5581675 RIDRETH1        WHR
11:          Mexican American 28.5600862 RIDRETH1     BMXBMI
12:            other Hispanic 27.8138462 RIDRETH1     BMXBMI
13:        non-Hispanic White 27.0137246 RIDRETH1     BMXBMI
14:        non-Hispanic Black 28.5602261 RIDRETH1     BMXBMI
15:        other non-Hispanic 27.1031377 RIDRETH1     BMXBMI
16:            No High School 14.9154844 DMDEDUC2 CIGARETTES
17:   High School, No Diploma 15.5943692 DMDEDUC2 CIGARETTES
18:  HS Diploma or Equivalent 15.5258469 DMDEDUC2 CIGARETTES
19:    Some college/AA degree 13.6358341 DMDEDUC2 CIGARETTES
20: College graduate or above 11.7456132 DMDEDUC2 CIGARETTES
21:            No High School 27.3320919 DMDEDUC2     BMXBMI
22:   High School, No Diploma 27.4109358 DMDEDUC2     BMXBMI
23:  HS Diploma or Equivalent 27.7410707 DMDEDUC2     BMXBMI
24:    Some college/AA degree 27.6298412 DMDEDUC2     BMXBMI
25: College graduate or above 26.7682926 DMDEDUC2     BMXBMI
26:            No High School  0.5774948 DMDEDUC2        WHR
27:   High School, No Diploma  0.5662341 DMDEDUC2        WHR
28:  HS Diploma or Equivalent  0.5669633 DMDEDUC2        WHR
29:    Some college/AA degree  0.5639211 DMDEDUC2        WHR
30: College graduate or above  0.5479236 DMDEDUC2        WHR
                          get       mean   catvar    calcvar
```

I want to produce a barplot for each combination of `catvar`-`calcvar` (eg, RIDRETH1 vs CIGARETTES, RIDRETH1 vs WHR) with a bar for each entry in `get`.

For example, this is (an ugly idea of) what I want for one `catvar`: RIDRETH1 vs CIGARETTES, WHR, and BMXBMI:

[image]

```
ggplot(data=data[data$catvar=="RIDRETH1"], aes(x=get, y=mean)) +
    facet_grid(calcvar ~ catvar, scales = "free_y") + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

However, if I attempt to use two `catvar`s (ie, show both RIDRETH1 *and* DMDEDUC2), the whole thing goes to hell:

[image]

```
ggplot(data=data[data$catvar=="RIDRETH1"], aes(x=get, y=mean)) +
    facet_grid(calcvar ~ catvar, scales = "free_y") + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Here's the code and the basic ggplot:

```
data=structure(list(get = c("Mexican American", "other Hispanic", 
"non-Hispanic White", "non-Hispanic Black", "other non-Hispanic", 
"Mexican American", "other Hispanic", "non-Hispanic White", "non-Hispanic Black", 
"other non-Hispanic", "Mexican American", "other Hispanic", "non-Hispanic White", 
"non-Hispanic Black", "other non-Hispanic", "No High School", 
"High School, No Diploma", "HS Diploma or Equivalent", "Some college/AA degree", 
"College graduate or above", "No High School", "High School, No Diploma", 
"HS Diploma or Equivalent", "Some college/AA degree", "College graduate or above", 
"No High School", "High School, No Diploma", "HS Diploma or Equivalent", 
"Some college/AA degree", "College graduate or above"), mean = c(6.74236799891251, 
9.39550816502028, 15.9486910291741, 10.2582134840889, 11.7396250210344, 
0.581232525625264, 0.568899901864229, 0.558711316230234, 0.561402759873007, 
0.558167495000229, 28.5600862089255, 27.8138462232903, 27.0137245744966, 
28.5602261242299, 27.1031376882496, 14.9154843636288, 15.5943692351338, 
15.5258469143284, 13.6358341183803, 11.7456132495542, 27.3320918541377, 
27.4109358360509, 27.7410707468688, 27.6298412194686, 26.7682926409561, 
0.577494827685547, 0.566234093777988, 0.566963343644022, 0.563921078038311, 
0.547923552981604), catvar = c("RIDRETH1", "RIDRETH1", "RIDRETH1", 
"RIDRETH1", "RIDRETH1", "RIDRETH1", "RIDRETH1", "RIDRETH1", "RIDRETH1", 
"RIDRETH1", "RIDRETH1", "RIDRETH1", "RIDRETH1", "RIDRETH1", "RIDRETH1", 
"DMDEDUC2", "DMDEDUC2", "DMDEDUC2", "DMDEDUC2", "DMDEDUC2", "DMDEDUC2", 
"DMDEDUC2", "DMDEDUC2", "DMDEDUC2", "DMDEDUC2", "DMDEDUC2", "DMDEDUC2", 
"DMDEDUC2", "DMDEDUC2", "DMDEDUC2"), calcvar = c("CIGARETTES", 
"CIGARETTES", "CIGARETTES", "CIGARETTES", "CIGARETTES", "WHR", 
"WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "BMXBMI", "BMXBMI", "BMXBMI", "BMXBMI", 
"BMXBMI", "CIGARETTES", "CIGARETTES", "CIGARETTES", "CIGARETTES", 
"CIGARETTES", "BMXBMI", "BMXBMI", "BMXBMI", "BMXBMI", "BMXBMI", 
"WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "WHR", "WHR")), .Names = c("get", "mean", "catvar", "calcvar"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

ggplot(data=data, aes(x=get, y=mean)) +
    facet_grid(calcvar ~ catvar, scales = "free_y") +
    geom_bar(stat="identity") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Any suggestions for how to get `facet_grid` not to repeat the bar names?

Comment: Try freeing all scales `scales = "free"`

Comment: @PierreLafortune That was far too easy. :)